# Static UITableView with Custom section headers?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` that's responsible for a static `UITableView`. Now, I've set it as a `group` in the `UIStoryboard` and I've also added it as a child view controller to another `UIViewController`. The problem is when I try to modify the `viewForHeaderInSection` to set a custom header. I see the header itself, but the `UILabel` for the header is not being shown. I'm not sure why.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.hex("DEE6EA")
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: headerView.frame.width, height: headerView.frame.height))
    label.textColor = .red
    //UIColor.hex("96A6AE")

    switch section {
    case 0:
        label.text = "Something"
    case 1:
        label.text = "eawda"
    case 2:
        label.text = "eawda"
    case 3:
        label.text = "eawda"
    case 4:
        label.text = "eawda"
    case 5:
        label.text = "eawda"
    default:
        break
    }

    headerView.addSubview(label)
    return headerView
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I forgot to give the `headerView` a frame. That's why.